# Problems while reshaping previous np.ravel

Tags: python, np

Good evening,

I've got a problem at my code; I wanna apply something (*Pyneb ®*) into a matrix (74 x 95). I've also defined some of my variable as *np.nan*, in case their value are equal or less then data error. However, when writing it to *np.ravel(R)*, instead of writing *np.nan*, it simply doesn't write anything, causing an error due to modified matrix size. 
(Some part of) The code is as below:

```
fs2[fs2<=3*errorfs2] = np.nan
fs1[fs1<=3*errorfs1] = np.nan
R = fs2/fs1
dens = []
for p in np.ravel(R): 
#    print(p)
    d = diags.getCrossTemDen('[NeIII] 3343/3930+','[SII] 6731/6716',1E-03,p)
    dens.append(d)
```

So, what I wanna do is: when fs1 and fs2 are defined as *np.nan*, the loop writes *np.nan* into the *np.ravel(R)* as well.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't understand. Please show the reproducible code including unexpected and expected results.

Comment: It's running right now; when it stops, I'll post the error message here.

Comment: I'm not sure about reproducing the code here, since it has ~250 lines...

Comment: just create a minimal example [mcve] please. (basically remove getCrossTemDen from your example and show us exactly what is wrong). If getCrossTemDen is the problem then you need to narrow down where it goes wrong...)

Comment: But if I remove *getCrossTemDen* the code doesn't make sense; it's part of *Pyneb* routine, which I'm trying to work with. 
My doubt is: how to write *np.nan* "numbers" into the *np.ravel*, instead of leaving it's place blank - and making the *np.ravel* smaller - ?

Comment: That's why it prints the error: *ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged*.

Comment: Well I can't help you without an MCVE... Again if the error comes from your function we need to see the bit in it that causes the error.